# Fast startup spring boot in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, spring-boot, spring-tool-suite

I have an external jar in the lib folder of my project. When I enable fast startup in run configurations options of the app, the jar's class object is instantiated perfectly but when I uncheck it, it throws NoClassDefFoundError. Can someone please help in this. I am using STS and running it by 'run as spring boot app' in eclipse.

Comment: Probably something around classpath is going wrong. Hard to say what exactly, this not the kind of problem that can be debugged without the specific details of your project to reproduce it. So I suggest you raise a bug on STS 4 github issue tracker and attach a sample project as well as some step-by-step instructions what to do with it so that the problem can be reproduced and debugged.

Comment: Can you tell what exactly is the role of fast startup for spring boot in run configuration in eclipse?

Comment: The fast startup option adds some extra arguments the JVM launch command. Specifically these ones `-noverify -XX:TieredStopAtLevel=1`. These arguments can also be tweaked via preferences (Preferences >> Spring >> Boot).

Comment: Thinking about it a bit, this problem actually sounds familiar. I vaguely remember someone reporting a similar bug and this had something to do with the adding of these arguments somehow masking another bug in how STS calculates the launch arguments (i.e. bug only happened if this option was unchecked and caused something to go wrong with the computation of launch command). Are you on a recent version of STS? If not you may want to try that because I think that bug got fixed. If still a problem, please raise a bug ticket. This does seem like it is probably bug in STS.